# Proof of $42\mid (2\cdot 3^{21092020} +6)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am asked to show that $42\mid  (d_{21092020} +1)$, for $d_m = 5+ 2\cdot 3^m$, here is a proof I have to show this, using modular arithmetic. I want to make sure my reasoning is sound, and correct any errors in my logic.

$42\mid  (d_{m} +1)$

$\iff$ $\bar{d_m}+\bar{1} = \bar{0}$ . Where $\bar{}$ denotes $mod42$. Hence by definition of $d_m$, we have that

$\bar{5}+\bar{2}\cdot \bar{3}^m +\bar{1} = \bar{0}$

$\Rightarrow$ $\bar{2}\cdot \bar{3}^m = -\bar{6}$ $\implies$ $\bar{3}^m = -\bar{3}$.

$\bar{3}^m$ is cyclic with period 6, and that for $m=6k+4$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, then the relationship $\bar{3}^m = -\bar{3}$ holds. Notice that we can write $21092020=6k+4$, with $k=3515336$. Thus since $21092020$ can be written in this manner, then it must be true that $42\mid  (d_{21092020} +1)$.

Is this enough for a relatively basic proof? Do I need to add anything more?

Comment: It is not true that $3^m\equiv -3\times 3^m\pmod {42}$.

Comment: Perhaps you would find it simpler to note that $42=2\times 3\times 7$.  Now it is obvious that $2$ and $3$ divide your expression, so you just have to check $7$.

Comment: Hint: $42 | 6n$ iff $7 | n$.

Comment: Hint: $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Comment: @lulu That could also definitely work, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: And there was a period at the end of $\bar{3}^m = -\bar{3}$, I wasn't saying $\bar{3}^m = -\bar{3} \cdot \bar{3}^m$, made it clear now hopefully.

Comment: Dividing by $2$ in the last implication is not valid because $2$ is not coprime to $42$.

Comment: It's clearly divisible by $6$ so you need only check divisibility by $7,\,$ whuch follows immediately by mod order reduction in the first linked dupe, i.e $\,2^{\color{#c00}{6}}\equiv 1\pmod 7\,$ so $\,n\equiv 4\pmod 6\Rightarrow 3^n\equiv 3^4\equiv 4\,$ so $\,2\cdot 3^n+6\equiv 2\cdot 4+6\equiv 0\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler way that you would establish that $42$ divides $N \doteq 2×3^{21092020}+6$ is to show that both $6$ divides $N$, and $7$ divides $N$.

Now $6$ divides $N$ as you can easily see. The crux is now showing that $7$ divides $N$, so this is what we show next. Now $$N \equiv_7 2×3^{21092020} +6 $$ so let's evaluate $3^{21092020} \pmod 7$. To this end, note that $$3^{21092020} \equiv_7 3^{21092020 \pmod 6}, $$ and so as $21092020 \equiv_6 4$, it follows that
$$3^{21092020} \equiv_7 3^4 =81 \equiv_7 4,$$, and so $$3^{21092020} \pmod 7 = 4.$$ Thus, $$N \equiv_7 2×(3^{21092020} \pmod 7) +6$$
$$\equiv_7 (2×4) + 6 \equiv_7 1-1 =0.$$ So $N \equiv_7 0$ and thus $7$ indeed divides $N$. And, as both $6$ and $7$ divide $N$, it follows that $42$ indeed divides $N$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

let $n=2*3^m+6$
$m\equiv 4\pmod{6}$
by FLT, $3^m\equiv 3^4\equiv 4\pmod{7}$
$n\equiv 2*4+6\equiv 0\pmod{7}$
since n is divisible by 2,3,7, it is divisible by 42.

Comment: That logic does not work. $3^{6}=729 \equiv 4 \mod 5$ but if $3^6 \equiv 3^{1}=3 \implies 3^{6} \equiv 3 \mod 5$.

Comment: i dont understand the second part. why $3^6\equiv 3^1\pmod{5}$?

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you did now, edit your answer and I will upvote instead, but I think you should clarify that step.

Comment: edited. though not sure whether i should explain what is FLT.